# DensityPlot3D shows white areas even if the function has values which should be colored

Tags: plotting, bugs, color

I have already searched for hours for a solution but didn't find anything yet. I neither understand why my problem even occurs since the function is well defined in the white areas in the picture.

The problem occurs as follows: I wanna draw a Density plot for a function with three arguments:

```
DensityPlot3D[1/(1 - x*y*z), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
 ColorFunction -> "BrightBands", ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{Automatic, {0, 2}}], Right],  
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]
[image]

The result is a plot which is mainly white where it actually should be colored according to the legend.
Does anybody know what's the problem ?

EDIT: The problem doesn't appear when I plot the inverse function instead of the original one. But the singularities of the original one are treated correctly so there should be no problem either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug, and the cause goes back to at least 10.2. The workaround is to make the color function used by `Raster3D` a little more permissive, e.g.

```
DensityPlot3D[1/(1 - x*y*z), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "BrightBands", ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
  PlotPoints -> 5, PlotLegends -> Automatic] /. #1 >= 0.5 -> #1 >= 0.49
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I set the PlotPoints to 100 like in my example and it did what i wanted to have.

Comment: @Levigeddon You're welcome. I used `PlotPoints -> 5` as it was easier to dig into. :)

Comment: @Levigeddon just a side note. The local "economy" on this site runs on votes and accepting answers that work best. So, please do both.